# Converting python webcrawler to 3.4 from 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, python-3.4

For this code I am converting a working python webcrawler from 2.7 to 3.4. I've made some modifications but I still get errors when running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\testCrawler.py", line 11, in <module>
    for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 206, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

This is the code itself, please tell me if you see what the syntax errors are.

```
#! C:\python34

import re
import urllib.request

textfile = open('depth_1.txt','wt')
print ("Enter the URL you wish to crawl..")
print ('Usage  - "http://phocks.org/stumble/creepy/" <-- With the double quotes')
myurl = input("@> ")
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I):
        print (i)  
        for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.request.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
                print (ee)
                textfile.write(ee+'\n')
textfile.close()
```

Comment: you need to decode the response from `read` into a `str`.

Comment: Though please - use an HTML parser to parse html, not regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read()
```

to for example

```
urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read().decode('utf-8')
```

What happens here is `.read()` returning `bytes` instead of `str` like it was in python 2.7, so it has to be decoded using some encoding.